# What is the significance of Black Widow saying "You could at least recognize me" to Bucky?

Tags: dialogue, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america-civil-war

In Captain America: Civil War, Black Widow says "You could at least recognise me" while fighting a 'hypnotised' Bucky. Most people suggest that it's simply a reference to her past encounters with him from The Winter Soldier and prior to that film, and possibly there relationship from the comics.

> **Natasha Romanoff:** I know who killed Fury. Most of the intelligence community doesn't believe he exists. The ones that do call him the Winter Soldier. He's credited over two dozen assassinations in the last 50 years.
> **Steve Rogers:** So he's a ghost story.
> **Natasha Romanoff:** Five years ago I was escorting a nuclear engineer out of Iran, somebody shot at my tires near Odessa. We lost control, went straight over a cliff, I pulled us out, but the Winter Soldier was there. I was covering my engineer, so he shot him straight *through* me. -[IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1843866/quotes)

Black Widow was a former KGB operative before joining SHIELD.

> "At a young age[5], Romanoff was recruited by the KGB." -[Marvel Cinematic Universe Wiki](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Black_Widow)

Bucky Barnes was part of the Winter Soldier Program which was a Soviet/Hydra program. And apparently was given his name because of his work with the KGB.

> "The Winter Soldier Program was a top secret Soviet project started by Arnim Zola that involved brainwashing American hero James Buchanan Barnes and turning him into a deadly assassin for HYDRA using a serum similar to the Super Soldier Serum." -[Marvel Cinematic Universe Wiki](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Winter_Soldier_Program)
>
> "Receiving vast training from HYDRA, Barnes became a formidable fighter and an even more ruthless killer. His experiences with the KGB would earn him the name of the "Winter Soldier." -[Marvel Cinematic Universe Wiki](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Winter_Soldier)

My question(s), is it possible that Black Widow saying "You could at least recognise me" had much more significance than just referencing Captain America: The Winter Soldier and her experience in Iran?

I understand that it may be a stretch and she hasn't really given any other indication that this may be the case. Being that she is apparently one of the worlds top spies, like Fury, she holds her cards close to her chest. Could they have crossed paths before while she was still with the KGB, but she is yet to explain/admit this?

I also understand that similar questions have been asked on here before. However these questions and the answers provided do not take into consideration that the comment was referring to something that is yet to be properly explained. The answers dismiss the comment as simply being sarcastic and/or referencing Captain America: The Winter Soldier. Whereas I'd like input on whether or not the comment was or could be much more significant than this.

Comment: Bye-Bye Bikinis. Yes, its just a reference to his sniping.

Comment: Seems like it's more significant than that. It seems like kind of a weird comment to make.

Comment: That question and the answers do not consider the possibility that they'd crossed paths while they were both with the Soviets. They present the idea that it is simply a reference to The Winter Soldier. My question goes beyond this.

Comment: If this is not a duplicate any answer would be speculative /opinion based and so *likely* off-topic.

Comment: "Off-topic" meaning what exactly? I am asking whether the comment may have more significance that what people have already suggested. So that is the topic...right? I understand that the responses will be speculative at this point. If you're saying that that means this is the wrong place for this question then I will consider deleting it, after getting input from others on whether or not this is the wrong place for this question. Sorry, I'm kind of new around here.

Comment: The question, had it not been a dupe, would be answerable with proof, and not off-topic, according to the rules of the site.

Comment: As for the dupe, the reality is that the two questions are the same. As far as any public information that is known, the line was a direct reference to the earlier scene, and there is no deeper history between BW and TWS

Comment: *Five years ago I was escorting a nuclear engineer out of Iran, somebody shot at my tires near Odessa.* I really can't understand this line. Odessa is in Ukraine. Did Black Widow leave Iran with the scientist and then they were attacked in Ukraine, or the screenwriters mistakenly thought Odessa is in Iran?